# Execute SQLite Inserts in several foreach loops in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert, foreach

this is my code I have:

I have read that setting up the CommandText should happen only once and not in a loop... but how do I then get the individually item data from the foreach?

Someone smart enough to refactor that code, that would be nice :)

```
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = DataAccess.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction())
{  
    using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(DataAccess.ConnectionManager))
    {
        // How can I add the parameters here if they are only known in the foreach loop?
        com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@date", day.SchooldayDate));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@periodnumber", period.PeriodNumber));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@schoolclasscode", period.SchoolclassCode));


        foreach (var week in weekList)
        {
            foreach (var day in week.Days)
            { 
                foreach (var period in day.Periods)
                {
                    com.CommandText = "Insert into tablename (date,periodnumber,schoolclasscode) Values (@date,@periodnumber,@schoolclasscode)";

                }
            }
        }

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    trans.Commit();                
}
```

UPDATE: The solution that works!

```
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = DataAccess.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(DataAccess.ConnectionManager))
                {
                    com.CommandText = "Insert into lessonday (lessondate,lessonnumber,schoolclasscode) VALUES (@lessondate,@lessonnumber,@schoolclasscode)";

                    SQLiteParameter p1 = new SQLiteParameter("@lessondate", DbType.DateTime);
                    SQLiteParameter p2 = new SQLiteParameter("@lessonnumber", DbType.Int32);
                    SQLiteParameter p3 = new SQLiteParameter("@schoolclasscode", DbType.String);

                    com.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    com.Parameters.Add(p2);
                    com.Parameters.Add(p3);

                    foreach (var week in weekList)
                    {
                        foreach (var day in week.Days)
                        {
                            p1.Value = day.SchooldayDate;
                            foreach (var period in day.Periods)
                            {
                                p2.Value = period.PeriodNumber;
                                p3.Value = period.SchooclassCode;

                                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the right way to do it!! Using parameterized queries and bundling your inserts into one large transaction makes Sqlite much faster.

Comment: yes it was terrible fast 4000 insert in less than a felt second :)

Comment: it was even more crazy in 0,488 seconds inserted 40K rows with 5 columns haha. Sqlite is crazy fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just move the loops:

```
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = DataAccess.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction()) 
{  
  foreach (var week in weekList)
  {
    foreach (var day in week.Days)
    { 
      foreach (var period in day.Periods)
      {
        using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(...))
        {   
          com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(...));
          com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(...));
          com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(...));
          com.CommandText = "Insert into ...";
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  trans.Commit();                
}
```

However, that seems a little ugly to me. I don't know how the SQLite provider will behave, but I think it would be at least worth *trying* to create the `SQLiteCommand` as per your original code, adding the parameters *but not their values*... and then moving the `ExecuteNonQuery` code into the innermost foreach loop. Something like this:

```
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = DataAccess.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction())
{  
  using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(DataAccess.ConnectionManager))
  {   
    com.CommandText = "Insert into ...";
    SQLiteParameter p1 = com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(...));
    SQLiteParameter p2 = com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(...));
    SQLiteParameter p3 = com.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(...));
    foreach (var week in weekList)
    {
      p1.Value = week;
      foreach (var day in week.Days)
      { 
        p2.Value = day;
        foreach (var period in day.Periods)
        {
          p3.Value = period;               
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  trans.Commit();                
}
```

Just to reiterate, I don't know if that will work - but I'd *hope* it would.

Comment: @Lisa: I suspect it's got the wrong type. Try creating the parameters with the appropriate DbType.

Comment: yes just did before you posted this and I removed my comment HAHA see it updated again :P

OK thank you Jon now I can go sleeping good night ;)